# Exclude nodes without property when using Reduce function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a factory node and a bunch of nodes created using the factory. The factory is the start of my path. I want to go to all the created nodes and perform some arithmetic on one property and total the results. The problem is the factory node does not have the property and i can't figure out how to remove that node from my path or ignore it during the reduce function. Here is a simplified form of my query.

START FactoryNode = node(30) MATCH Path = FactoryNode -[:CREATEDNODES]-> CreatedNode RETURN reduce(total = 0, n in nodes(Path) : total + n.Score);

The server gets mad because FactoryNode does not have the property Score.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use a function in the expression of reduce, but can you try

```
START FactoryNode = node(30)
MATCH Path = FactoryNode -[:CREATEDNODES]-> CreatedNode
RETURN reduce(total = 0, n in nodes(Path) : total + COALESCE(n.Score?,0));
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to do it. Or you can filter before you reduce if it's something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking for properties, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-property-exists